# Неправильное отображение сайтов в EI (старые версии)

Tags: joomla, css, браузер

Доброго времени суток!

Проблема №1: Этот же сайт в IE отображается вообще в раскорячку и даже F5 не помогает. Точную версию я не знаю, но вот вопрос: Может ли в старых версиях IE отображаться неправильно? И если да то почему оно отображается не правильно?

Comment: Может ли в старых версиях IE отображаться неправильно? —
О сколько вам открытий чудных готовит интернета дух...

Comment: хорошо сказано) я бы даже сказал, что и в файерфоксах и в хромах и в опере может по разному отображаться, но больше всего проблем огребете в IE :) да еще и что в вашем понятии "старый IE"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

страница может и отображаться неправильно в разных браузерах, и даже версиях.

Решение: использовать библиотеки jQuery, и/или использовать заплатки.

Заплатка это такой JavaScript, который в зависимости от браузера выводит определённый элемент так как данному браузеру нравится.